# HttpURLConnection java.io.FileNotFoundException in android 5.0.2

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

i am using below code for downloading pdf file from server and store into sdcard. its running fine on android 4.4 device. while its not working on android 5.0.2 device.

```
public static String downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
        try {

            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
            urlConnection.connect();


            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
            result = "true";
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "false";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "false";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = "false";
        }
        return result;
    }
```

On Line:  `InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();` i got `java.io.FileNotFoundException` error.

i tried so many things but didnt work. help me to solved this bug.

Comment: Try this : `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));`
And then read like this: 
 `String line = reader.readLine();
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                while (line != null) {
                                      //
                    }`

Comment: @RobertS as i said i am getting error before reading stream.